# Writing a cookie when back pressed in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to write a cookie when I detect a back press in the browser. This is working correctly and writing the cookie when a back press is detected. Problem is that when my page I am going back to loads it does not always have that new cookie value in its $_COOKIE array. This is strange because sometimes it is there and sometimes not, I'm thinking this is a race condition. Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the cookie is accessed with `document.cookie`. `$_COOKIE` is a PHP thing.

Comment: Yea I am trying to detect if it was a back press in PHP. The javascript will set the cookie and PHP will read it.

Comment: Is your setup something like this: PHP document sends data, cookie is modified in JavaScript, data is send to the **same** document. The important part is that it is the same script over and over again. Cookies are normally relative the current path (but can also be set to apply to the whole domain)

Comment: I have the path set to '/', which should be whole domain correct? And yes it goes back to the same page it was on before.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct path. Can you give us a minimal HTML/JavaScript + PHP setup?